# how to add check bo0x in selection box with multiple selection box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I used selection box with multiple selection now the problem is that it is selectable with ctrl+click of mouse. It is work properly but not that much prefrble to me and lookes like simple selection box and user cant get that its multiple selector not single.so thats why i want it with check box so user easly get it is multiple selector.please give apropriate solution thanks in advanced...

```
<select class="selopt" id="selPreLoc" name="SelPreLoc[]" multiple="multiple" size=5>
    <option label="No Preference">No Preference</option>
    <?php
    //<option value=-1 selected>No Preference</option>
    while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($GetCityRecord)) {
        if ($rec['City_Id'] == 30 || $rec['City_Id'] == 34 || $rec['City_Id'] == 35) {
            $others[$rec['City_Id']] = $rec['City'];
            continue;
        }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php $rec['City_Id']; ?>" <?php echo (isset($_POST['SelPreLoc']) && in_array($rec['City_Id'], $_POST['SelPreLoc'])) ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $rec['City']; ?>
        </option>
            <?php
        }
        foreach ($others as $ind => $val) {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $ind; ?>" <?php echo (isset($_POST['SelPreLoc']) && in_array($ind, $_POST['SelPreLoc'])) ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $val; ?>
        </option>
            <?php }
        ?>
</select>
<label class="formtxt" valign="bottom">Use Ctrl + Click to multi-select.</label></td>
```

I got many other solution with using div or other.

but i just want it with select option only is it posible if yes how .andi can fetch the result in mysql and i want that result with comma seprator in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

My code is not tested, since i do not have the data, but based on your logic, you can use it like this:

```
$theOthers = array(30, 34, 35);
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($GetCityRecord)) {
    if (in_array($rec['City_Id'], $theOthers)) {
        $others[$rec['City_Id']] = $rec['City'];
        continue;
    }
    $checked = '';
    if (isset($_POST['SelPreLoc']) && in_array($rec['City_Id'], $_POST['SelPreLoc'])) {
        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="<?php $rec['City_Id']; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> /> <?php echo $rec['City']; ?> <br />

    <?php
}
foreach ($others as $ind => $val) {
    $checked = '';
    if (isset($_POST['SelPreLoc']) && in_array($ind, $_POST['SelPreLoc'])) {
        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="<?php echo $ind; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> /> <?php echo $val; ?> <br />

    <?php
}
```

NOTE: I improved your code a littlebit with the `$theOthers` array, i think it's more readable.

When form is submitted, let's `var_dump($_POST["city"]);`

Comment: your given code gives only list of city with check box i want that list into the selection box is it posible